# JAXB override abstract method

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I'm kind of new to JAXB and parsing XSD-files into Java classes. 
The plan is to have an abstract class and multiple classes which extend the abstract class. All subclasses must override a specific method. 
What would be the best approach to achieve this goal? Hope someone can give me a hint.
Basically I've this implementation at the moment:

Abstract class XSD description:

```
<xs:complexType name="DataObject" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="dataType" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="match" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Now I'd like to override the getter for the 'match' object of the 'DataObject' abstract class in my subclasses XSD description file. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to override the `getMatch` method to do?

Comment: Basically I'd like to create different subclasses of a default type of class. Let's say my base was 'car', subclasses would be 'ferrari', 'porsche'. getMatch would return whether the size matters or the horsepower. Ideally the return type of the getMatch method would differ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that JAXB cannot make instances of abstract classes; hence you will need to bind the xml tag to concrete sub-classes of DataObject.

Example below shows a concrete StringMatchDataObject class; other classes can follow the same structure:

```
public abstract class DataObject {

  private String value;
  private String dataType;

  public String getValue() {
    return value;
  }
  public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
  public String getDataType() {
    return dataType;
  }
  public void setDataType(String dataType) {
    this.dataType = dataType;
  }

  public abstract String getMatch();
  public abstract void setMatch(String match);
}
```

---

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name="DataObject")
public class StringMatchDataObject extends DataObject {

  private String match;

  @Override
  public String getMatch() {
    return match;
  }

  @Override
  public void setMatch(String match) {
    this.match = match; 
  }

}
```

---

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class AppRun {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {

      StringMatchDataObject stringMatchDataObject = new StringMatchDataObject();
      stringMatchDataObject.setDataType("data type");
      stringMatchDataObject.setMatch("STRING MATCH");
      stringMatchDataObject.setValue("value");

      JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(StringMatchDataObject.class);
      Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
      m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
      m.marshal(stringMatchDataObject, System.out);
  }

}
```